# Can I make scripts use aliases instead of commands?

Tags: shell-script, alias

I have an alias for a command (I'm setting up a Python development environment)

```
alias python=~/virtualenv/bin/python
```

so that I can run `~/virtualenv/bin/python` by just typing `python`. Now in my project there is a shell script that goes, for example:

```
#!/bin/sh
python run-project.py
```

Can I make the script use my aliased `python` instead of the `python` it finds in `$PATH`, without making changes to the script?

Comment: Out of interest, why can't you change PATH?  Changing PATH and putting `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top of your python scripts seems easier.

Comment: @Mikel This is even better than your other answer. Can't accept comments, though.

Comment: I updated my answer to include that suggestion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

If you put your aliases in `~/.aliases`, then you can do

```
export BASH_ENV="~/.aliases"
somescript
```

This assumes your script starts with `#!/bin/bash`, because `#!/bin/sh` is a little less predictable.

Here's what I'd suggest:

1. Create ~/.bashenv
2. Move all the settings that you want to work in scripts from ~/.bashrc into ~/.bashenv
3. Add this at the top of your ~/.bashrc:
   `[ -f ~/.bashenv ] && source ~/.bashenv`
4. Put `BASH_ENV=~/.bashenv` in /etc/environment
5. Make your scripts start with `#!/bin/bash` if they don't already

Or, if you're using zsh, just move your aliases into ~/.zshenv.  zsh looks in that file automatically.

---

But maybe it's easier to just put `~/virtualenv/bin` near the front of your `PATH`, then change your Python scripts to have `#!/usr/bin/env python` as the first line.

Comment: Don't you mean `~/.bashenv` in step 4?

Comment: So I'll have to change the script anyway, from `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`? Can I just do `bash my-script`?

Comment: phunehehe: Yes, I think `bash my-script` will work if you still do steps 1-4.

Comment: I don't recommend using aliases in scripts. It won't work if someone else runs your script, or if you run the script under `sudo` or other privilege elevation method. And it doesn't allow you to change the `virtualenv` per execution, which would be the main point of not having `~/virtualenv/bin` in your `PATH` permanently. Adding the directory in front of the `PATH` when needed is the best method.

Answer (score 4):

Supposing that your alias file is "**~/.bash_aliases**", put this in your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s expand_aliases
source ~/.bash_aliases
python run-project.py
```

([via](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1496//1498#1498))

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can always `source` your script to forcely use the aliases. For example, let's assume you have an alias of `rm` in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias rm='moveToTrash'
```

while `moveToTrash` is a program in your `/usr/bin`. Now you have a script named `test.bash` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

which rm
```

When `test.bash` is execute directly, you can see the output `/bin/rm`, while `source test.bash` will get the output

```
alias rm='moveToTrash'
    /usr/bin/moveToTrash
```