# how does CentOS load bash_alias file?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, centos, alias, bashrc

I'm used to [Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/17536/), where I just create a `.bash_aliases` file and away you go.  In `CentOS`, how do I get `.bashrc` to [load](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1496/) the `.bash_aliases` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i look into my .bashrc i see the following code

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

This sources the .bash_aliases if present.

May be you have simply add this fragment to your .bashrc in your centos box.