# Symlink to a bash script unable to "see" an alias

Tags: shell-script, shell, symlink

I'm having some difficulty understanding a subtlety of how a bash script works with arguments when it's accessed via a symbolic link. The issue is most easily explained with commands and their output:

```
$ type ll
ll is aliased to `ls -Alt --color=auto'

$ cat myshellscript
#!/bin/bash
type $1

$ ls -l myshellscript
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 20 Aug 22 19:55 myshellscript

$ . myshellscript ll
ll is aliased to `ls -Alt --color=auto'

$ ls -l /usr/local/bin
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Aug 22 19:56 mss -> /home/pi/sh/myshellscript

$ mss ls
ls is /bin/ls

$ echo "OK, that worked"
OK, that worked

$ mss ll
/usr/local/bin/st: line 2: type: ll: not found

$ echo "Why didn't that work?"
Why didn't that work?
```

Comment: In `. myshellscript ll` you are *sourcing* the script whereas in `mss ll` you are just *running* it. See also [Can't use alias in script, even if I define it just above!](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368246/cant-use-alias-in-script-even-if-i-define-it-just-above)

Comment: If you run `. mss ll` it will work, for the reasons pointed out by steeldriver

Comment: Also relevant: [What is the difference between sourcing ('.' or 'source') and executing a file in bash?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/43882)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expansion of aliases is disabled by default inside scripts: see for example

- [Can't use alias in script, even if I define it just above!](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/368258/65304)

When you execute

```
. myshellscript ll
```

you are not just running `myshellscript`, you are *sourcing* it into the current (interactive) shell, where the alias **is** expanded. In contrast, when you run

```
mss ls
```

you are simply running the script, and alias expansion does not occur - as expected. You would see the same result if you had run `./myshellscript ll` instead of `. myshellscript ll`

Comment: The use of expanded here is confusing to me, as I would expect that to mean `. myshellscript ll` literally turns into `. myshellscript ls -Alt --color=auto`. But as I understand it, `ll` is simply not defined in the child process created by `./myshellscript ll`.

Comment: @Jonathan "Expanded" might not be the clearest way to state it. If `ll` were used as a command in the script, it would not be expanded as an alias; because of this, `type` ignores the fact that there's an alias by that name and reports that there's no (relevant) command by that name.