# Command works but permission denied error when executed from script

Tags: ssh, permissions, remote

The below command works fine from my localhost and I get the desired output. See below

```
$ ssh -o ConnectTimeout=7  -o BatchMode=yes root@10.9.60.26 "echo WORKS;exit"
Output:
WORKS
```

Now, I put this command in a script file `test.sh` having sufficient execution privileges

```
$ cat test.sh
segment=$(ssh -o ConnectTimeout=7  -o BatchMode=yes root@10.9.60.26 "echo WORKS;exit")
echo "SEGMENT $segment"
```

I don't get the desired output. Infact I get the below error:

```
$ ./test.sh
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
SEGMENT
```

I was expecting

```
SEGMENT WORKS
```

Now, the Permission denied error goes away but

Can you please suggest what could be the issue ?

Comment: How are you running your script (crontab?)? How are you authenticating with the remote system (public key in a ssh-agent?)?

Comment: @Kusalananda i updated my original post to answer your question.

Comment: I got the problem. alias ssh with private key `ssh -i /<path_to_private_key>` was set is what it was working on local command line but in the script I had to specify the private key explicitly.

Comment: Yes, aliases are not expanded in `bash` scripts. See e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368246/cant-use-alias-in-script-even-if-i-define-it-just-above

Comment: @Ashar you should write you solution as an answer, this might help someone in same situation.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I used an alias

```bsh
alias ssh=ssh -i /app/private_key
```

stored in the user profile. However, this setting doesn't take effect in a shell script (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1496/377345) e.g.), so I had to explicitly call

```bsh
ssh -i app/private_key
```

in the script. This resolved the issue.