# bash function command not found in cronjob

Tags: zsh, cron, amazon-linux

In my crontab , I set following bash function and applied it for my job. it is indicated to add timestamp to the log.

```
adddate() {
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        printf '%s %s\n' "$(date)" "$line";
    done
}

30 06 * * * root $binPath/zsh/test.zsh | adddate 1>>$logPath/log.csv 2>>$errorLogPath/error.txt
```

But when I see `error.txt`  the bash function didn't work well.

`/bin/bash: adddate: command not found`

Where is root cause of this?

If someone has opinion, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if the package is available on amazon linux, but as an alternative to a shell function: [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) provides a `ts` utility that can add timestamps to lines received on standard input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cron doesn't accept shell functions, create a script like

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
adddate() {
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        printf '%s %s\n' "$(date)" "$line";
    done
}
$binPath/zsh/test.zsh | adddate 1>>$logPath/log.csv 2>>$errorLogPath/error.txt
```

and put that in cron.

(I'm assuming here that you used `$binPath` and `$logPath` for the purpose of this question. If this isn't the case you have to set them in the script)

Setting `SHELL=/bin/bash` in your `crontab` *might* be a way to use shell functions.
(I didn't try it and it would surprise me if it works). But even if it works I would certainly not advise it.

Comment: More than that, a crontab file isn't a shell script at all - the only "active" lines it supports aside from the actual cron jobs are simple environment assignments. See for example [crontab (5)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use alias instead of function:

Add .profile or .bashrc file in your home dir:

```
alias adddate="while IFS= read -r line; do printf '%s %s\n' "$(date)" "$line"; done"
```

Then in your crontab:

```
30 06 * * * shopt -s expand_aliases; root $binPath/zsh/test.zsh | adddate 1>>$logPath/log.csv 2>>$errorLogPath/error.txt
```

Normally crontab (in other words a non-interactive shell) does not allow aliases either but you can activate that by `shopt -s expand_aliases`.

Comment: So, hmm, I wonder, does this really work for you? Because for one, I don't think a non-interactive Bash, like one started from cron reads `.bashrc` or `.profile`. Also, doing `shopt -s expand_aliases` and then calling an alias on the same line doesn't work, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/502257/170373 . And third, the shell cron launches might not be Bash to begin with, it depends on what `SHELL` is set to.

Comment: ... also the `root` in the OP's original cron job is presumably the username in a Debian-style "system wide" crontab rather than part of the command

Comment: Did you test that alias?

Comment: using alias in crontab is works with shopt -s expand_aliases for me. But there was a mistake it shoud not be &&, it should be semi colon.