# Bash: Alias not recognized in shell interpolation

Tags: bash, alias, command-substitution

```
~$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

```
~$ alias bab=python
~$ $(echo bab)
bash: bab: command not found
```

I'd expect bab to be turned to "python", but it seems it's not.

```
~$ $(echo alias)
alias bab='python'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
~$ bab
Python 3.10.1 (main, Dec 11 2021, 17:22:55) [GCC 11.1.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

The alias is recognized though, and works outside the interpolation. Why won't it work inside the interpolation?

`eval` works:

```
~$ eval $(bab)
Python 3.10.1 (main, Dec 11 2021, 17:22:55) [GCC 11.1.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I still wonder why

Comment: What do you mean by "works"? With `eval $(bab)` you would evaluate the _output_ of `bab`. Yes, it runs `python`, but that's _before_ it gets to `eval`.  What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: `eval $(bab)` isn't doing what you think it's doing - you're seeing the `bab` alias running python. When that's completed the results will get passed to `eval`. You can see this by running a command in the `python` session such as `print("date\n")`

Comment: I reopened. This Q is not a duplicate of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1496/why-doesnt-my-bash-script-recognize-aliases).

Comment: though `$(echo xyz)` in particular is pretty much useless, same as `echo $(zyx)`. But I assume you actually have some other expansion there.

Comment: If you do `eval $(bab)`, or equally, `eval $(python)`, and try e.g. `print("hello")` in the interpreter, you'll see the output doesn't appear on the screen. Instead, when you exit the interpreter, Bash will complain about not finding the command `hello`... When starting the python interpreter in a command substitution, it's output is captured by the shell. It just prints the command line to the terminal, bypass the command substitution. You probably don't want that. Something like `var=$(python script.py)` would make more sense, of course.

Comment: Also note that using `$(anything)` would not just run `anything`, it would expand the output of that command, split the output on the characters in `$IFS`, and apply filename globbing on the resulting strings. Then it would treat the first word as a command. It's unclear why you are attempting to use this syntax.

Comment: @glennjackman how do I put in a vote for a suggested dup instead of wielding a hammer?

Comment: The tag gold badge comes with surprising powers sometimes. Perhaps just a comment?

Comment: It's because $() starts a subshell without the alias of the parent shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aliases get expanded **before** command substitution, documented in [3.1.1 Shell Operation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Operation). The "bab" that gets executed after `$(echo bab)` *will not* be handled as an alias.

Try using a function instead:

```bsh
unalias bab
bab() { python "$@"; }
$(echo bab)       # launches a python shell
```

Comment: Why would you ever want to use `$(echo bab)` in place of just `bab` though?

Comment: Normally you wouldn't of course. I approached this question more as a "why does bash behave like this in this corner case".

Comment: My real usecase is that inside `$()` I had a command that prints what I want to run (specifically, `jq <package.json .scripts.test -r`). Happy to explain more in case someone is interested.

Answer (score 1):

From `man bash`

> ***Aliases***  allow  a string to be substituted for a word when it is used as the first word of a simple command.