# autossh always exits in error

Tags: ssh, autossh

I've aliased `ssh` to `autossh -M0` for convenience, and it works well.

However it always exits in error, which causes problems with my scripts.

e.g.

```bash
ssh me@myserver 'true'      # equivalent to:  autossh -M0 me@myserver 'true'
echo $?     # 1
```

How do I fix this?

(A workaround in scripts, it to use `/usr/bin/ssh` instead of `ssh`. But I'd like to fix this if possible.)

Comment: do you have this problem? [Why doesn't my Bash script recognize aliases?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1496/72456)

Comment: I tried `shopt -s expand_aliases; ssh myserver 'true'; echo $?` and now it gives `0`! Thanks @αғsнιη! Maybe you could add as another answer? I guess both answers are correct for different reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the man page:

> There is a "starting gate" time. If the first ssh process fails within the first few seconds of being
> started, autossh assumes that it never made it "out of the starting gate", and exits. This is to handle
> initial failed authentication, connection, etc. This time is 30 seconds by default, and can be adjusted
> (see the AUTOSSH_GATETIME environment variable below).

So, setting AUTOSSH_GATETIME to zero solves that:

```
AUTOSSH_GATETIME=0 ssh me@myserver 'true'
echo $?     # 0
```

If you are not typing a password or passphrase, you can also use the `-f` flag of `autossh` (which you could add to the alias):

```
ssh -f me@myserver 'true'
echo $?     # 0
```

Comment: That's weird, because if ssh failed then I'd understand why this works... but ssh doesn't fail. Regardless, it works for me, so thank you Eduardo!

Comment: Well, the manpage is not clear, but the actual behaviour in the source code is this: if `ssh` exits before AUTOSSH_GATETIME then it is considered a *premature exit*, regardless of the actual `ssh` exit code. If you set AUTOSSH_DEBUG you will will see either `ssh exited prematurely with status 0; autossh exiting` (exit code 1) or `ssh exited with status 0; autossh exiting` (no mention to *premature*, exit code 0).