# Bash set project-specific aliases, file not found

Tags: bash, windows, alias

I am on Windows and using GitBash to run shell scripts in bash that run python scripts.

How can I create a project-specific alias to define a specific python environment and run shell scripts through GitBash that use that environment?

This is a file called `test.sh`:

```
# misc notes at top, like a docstring
print("Hello")
# real file will instead say myPyScript.py etc.
```

I can successfully run this in GitBash with `C:/users/name/mypath/python.exe test.sh` and it returns "Hello" to the console.

Problem: I want to use a project-specific python environment whose path is defined with an alias.

Here's what I am trying, based on [Why doesn't my Bash script recognize aliases?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1496/why-doesnt-my-bash-script-recognize-aliases), and how it is failing:

This is a file called `.pyalias`:

```
alias mypython='C:/users/name/mypath/python.exe test.sh'
```

This is a file called `main_run_all.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# misc notes at top, like a docstring

shopt -s expand_aliases
source /.pyalias

mypython test.sh
# real file will instead say myPyScript.py etc
```

When I run `sh main_run_all.sh` I get `test.sh: line 6: source: .pyalias: file not found`

Here is the directory setup:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of this line:

```
source /.pyalias
```

should be:

```
source ./.pyalias
```